# CURL POST XML отправка

Tags: xml, post, php, curl, сокет

В общем-то суть не в том что я не могу CURLол отправить POST данные, а трабл в том что данные нужно передать не парно т.е. POSTом по HTTPS отправить XML данные.

но сервер принимает просто XML без параметра т.е. не ?data="<XML>" а просто XML как поток.

В голову просто ничего не лезет.

Может с сокетами попробовать?

Или кто что делал подобное. мне только направление подать, а то навалилось работы, сами понимаете (кто работает)

up

Comment: [socket_write][1]?


  [1]: http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-write.php

Comment: Вы уверены, что методом **POST** вы должны отправлять **поток**? o_O

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем прокатил бональный **curl** как ни странно.

Единственное что. На локалке не отправлялся запрос, на выделенном сервере отправился.

phpinfo показал одинаковые настройки.

В общем проблема решена. Всем спасибосы и респектос! шадоу +1

Answer (score 2):

отправка потока сокетом:

```
<?
$data = 'xml';
if ($s = @fsockopen(gethostbyname('somesite.com'), 443 /* https */, $errno, $errstr, 3 /* timeout*/)) {
  /* begin возможно ненужная часть, исходя из "принимает поток" */
  fwrite($s, 
    "POST /URI/ HTTP/1.1\r\n".
    "Host: somesite.com\r\n".
    "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n".
    "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n".
    "\r\n"
  );
  /* end */
  fwrite($s, $data);
  $response = '';
  do {
    $part = fread($s, 4096);
    $response .= $part;
  } while (strlen($part) == 4096); 
fclose($s);
} else die('Can\'t connect');
echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Ах да, если у вас `mb_func_overload == 'On'` - сношайтесь сами с определением длины строки)) Ибо fread/fwrite читают байты и возвращают кол-во байт.